# Share an external USB Hard drive connected to XP Home

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, home-networking

I want to share on my home network an external USB Hard drive connected to my netbook running XP Home.

My laptop and home PC (both running Win 7 Home Premium x64) can see the shared drive but cannot access it.

This is very frustrating as I can share other folders on the netbook but not the external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

If they can both see it but they can't use it, it's likely because the **users** group doesn't have permissions.  Keep in mind that accounts running in Win7 with UAC run as standard users, or the local **Users** group.  Accounts on XP, by default, run as Administrators.  It's possible that the drive was created and local users don't have permissions to read/write to it.

Another scenario is that XP, by default, authenticates everyone as Guest.

You can solve the problem by giving the **Users** group permission
Under XP, if you right click the shared drive, go under security and give the **Users** group the correct permissions.